# Pass data from c# to electron

Tags: c#, node.js, electron, ipc

I am loading electron from c# via process object. I want to pass data from c# to electron(nodejs) via process object(Inter process communication).

I have passed data in C# via standard input. But i am unable to get the data in node via standard output.

C# code to load electron and passing data via standard input.

```cs
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    WorkingDirectory = @"desktopApp",
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
    FileName = @"electron.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    //CreateNoWindow = true,
    Arguments = "app"
};

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

StreamWriter myStreamWriter = process.StandardInput;
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("jsonData\n"); //Data string passing
myStreamWriter.Close();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Electron main.js to get the data. Below event is not triggering at all.

```
process.stdout.on('data', (jsonData) => {
    console.log("data", jsonData);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a library now for Electron to C# via STDIN/STDOUT.  Here's the article: https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2019/02/27/electron-cgi/